# Adding filters to tabs

Tags: feature-request, question-lists

Due to the volume of questions being asked on SO every minute, I think it would be neat to be able to filter out questions that are on hold (or any other status) with a simple/quick dropdown menu so that those questions aren't mashed in with real (better put) questions. Just throwing out some options that come to mind:

- All (defaulted) - *both open and questions that are on hold*
- Open - *just open*
- On Hold - *questions that are on hold*

I'm sure there's other great options that can be put in there. With regards to a look and feel, I thought this might work:

[image]

All I know is that more and more questions are closed because of poor quality and/or lack of effort. It's becoming excessive and frankly, I don't care to see them.

Comment: One option given the current functionality is to use the search page over /questions

Comment: @Servy I figured that there _might_ be other ways to do this but I think a quick and easy way would be nice.